# Dragging and dropping a texture

Tags: texturing

I created a simple maze (via surface subdivision, extrusion, smooth shadows and edge split). Now I want to add some 'hedge' textures to the walls. When I drag and drop the texture, I seem to get just one color instead of a texture?

[image]
[image]

It seems only a few cells got the right texture?
[image]
[image]

Edit: I've set up the texture manually for some planes, but is it possible to automise this process?

[image]

Edit2: It works when I select everything at once and then adding the texture. When I add the texture a second time, it's just a green square.

Comment: Is the hedge texture tileable, also what render engine are you using?

Comment: You'll need to define a mapping for the texture. For the most control you might want to look into using a *UV map*

Comment: Have you tried rendering it? It may appear different that way instead of in the viewport.

Comment: @TheMinecrafterandBlendmist I imported and rendered it in Unity3D: I see only green diffuse walls

Answer (score 4):

I apologize if this answer is too basic or misunderstands your issue.

I created a blend file that I made by subdividing a plain, extruding a row of hedges along Z, and then applying a material with an image texture to the raised hedge.

The first image below is the material set-up in Cycles. The second is the view in Blender in Object mode at with Material View selected.

Here is a Dropbox link to the blend file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/6klf54mwkup0ysd/hedge.blend?dl=0

If this is the issue you were trying to address, let me know if it is incomplete....

[image]

[image]